# Problems with interfacing Nucleo-F446RE and ADF4153 via SPI

Tags: stm32, stm32cubemx, keil, nucleo

I am trying to interface with a [ADF4153](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ADF4153.pdf) device via SPI, the problem is that the ADF4153 is not responding. I expect the problem is with the SPI connection. The pin connections are as follows;

MOSI -> DATA,

SCK -> CLK,

D9 -> LE

Hardware initialization is done by STMCubeMX and the software is programmed in Keil uVision.

Here is my code.

```
#include "main.h"
SPI_HandleTypeDef hspi1;
void SystemClock_Config(void);
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void);
static void MX_SPI1_Init(void);
uint8_t array0[3];
uint8_t array1[3];
uint8_t array2[3];
uint8_t array3[3];
int main(void)
{
  HAL_Init();
  SystemClock_Config();
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_SPI1_Init();
    array0[0]=0x00;
    array0[1]=0x00;
    array0[2]=0x32;
    array1[0]=0x65;
    array1[1]=0x80;
    array1[2]=0x40;
    array2[0]=0xC2;
    array2[1]=0x17;
    array2[2]=0x00;
    array3[0]=0x00;
    array3[1]=0x00;
    array3[2]=0x03;
HAL_SPI_Transmit(&hspi1, array0, 3,10);
HAL_SPI_Transmit(&hspi1, array1, 3,10);
  while (1)
  {
//HAL_SPI_Transmit(&hspi1, array2, 3,10);
//HAL_SPI_Transmit(&hspi1, array3, 3,10);       
  }
} 
void SystemClock_Config(void)
{
  RCC_OscInitTypeDef RCC_OscInitStruct = {0};
  RCC_ClkInitTypeDef RCC_ClkInitStruct = {0};
  __HAL_RCC_PWR_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_PWR_VOLTAGESCALING_CONFIG(PWR_REGULATOR_VOLTAGE_SCALE3);  
  RCC_OscInitStruct.OscillatorType = RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSI;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSIState = RCC_HSI_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSICalibrationValue = RCC_HSICALIBRATION_DEFAULT;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLState = RCC_PLL_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLSource = RCC_PLLSOURCE_HSI;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLM = 16;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLN = 336;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLP = RCC_PLLP_DIV4;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLQ = 2;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLR = 2;
  if (HAL_RCC_OscConfig(&RCC_OscInitStruct) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.ClockType = RCC_CLOCKTYPE_HCLK|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_SYSCLK
                              |RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK1|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK2;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKSource = RCC_SYSCLKSOURCE_PLLCLK;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.AHBCLKDivider = RCC_SYSCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB1CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV2;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB2CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;

  if (HAL_RCC_ClockConfig(&RCC_ClkInitStruct, FLASH_LATENCY_2) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
}


static void MX_SPI1_Init(void)
{
  hspi1.Instance = SPI1;
  hspi1.Init.Mode = SPI_MODE_MASTER;
  hspi1.Init.Direction = SPI_DIRECTION_2LINES;
  hspi1.Init.DataSize = SPI_DATASIZE_8BIT;
  hspi1.Init.CLKPolarity = SPI_POLARITY_HIGH;
  hspi1.Init.CLKPhase = SPI_PHASE_2EDGE;
  hspi1.Init.NSS = SPI_NSS_SOFT;
  hspi1.Init.BaudRatePrescaler = SPI_BAUDRATEPRESCALER_32;
  hspi1.Init.FirstBit = SPI_FIRSTBIT_LSB;
  hspi1.Init.TIMode = SPI_TIMODE_DISABLE;
  hspi1.Init.CRCCalculation = SPI_CRCCALCULATION_DISABLE;
  hspi1.Init.CRCPolynomial = 10;
  if (HAL_SPI_Init(&hspi1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
}
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void)
{
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();
}
void Error_Handler(void)
{
}
#ifdef  USE_FULL_ASSERT
void assert_failed(uint8_t *file, uint32_t line)
{ 
}
#endif
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the datasheet

> When latch enable (LE) is high, the 22 bits that are clocked into the
>   input register on each rising edge of SCLK are transferred to the
>   appropriate latch

I don't see you driving that pin in your software.

Comment: That, and the bits are sent out LSB first. That's nice if the data in the arrays also are so that they can be sent LSB first, but the chip datasheet says bits are sent MSB first so usally it would make sense to send data in MSB first also.